# Insert multiple files into mysql

Tags: pdf, insert, multipartform-data, sql-insert

I am trying to create a form whereby I can select multiple files (they will be pdfs) and insert the file and the file's name into the database.

Html form works beautifully:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

But I can't seem to make the php work with it:

```
if(isset($_POST['files[]'])){
        $file_name = $_POST['files[]']['name'];
    $file_size =$_POST['files[]']['size'];
    $file_type=$_POST['files[]']['type'];}
    $query="INSERT INTO upload_data (`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
```

I also don't know how to insert the actual file, as opposed to just its properties.  Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I got how to upload multiple files, and also multiple file names, but I cannot do both at the same time.  Still need help.  The code is:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){    
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $filename) {
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO practice (name) VALUES('$filename')", $c) or die("six");
}
}
```

and

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){    
        foreach ($_FILES['files'] as $file) {
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO practice (file) VALUES('$file')", $c) or die("six");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get information about uploaded files, you need to use the `$_FILES` variable instead of the `$_POST` variable : http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php